# Get JSON Schema from dynamic (or actually JSON data) using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to get JSON Schema from a JSON entity using Newtonsoft JSON.Net.

This works as expected:

```
dynamic customObject = new
{
    Title = "Test"
};
var schemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator { };
var schema = schemaGenerator.Generate(customObject.GetType());
```

This works fine. The `.Properties` property of the schema shows the 'Title' property with details.

However my source for the schema is a piece of **JSON data**. So I first serialize it to `dynamic`:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customObject);
dynamic customObjectAfterSerialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator { };
JsonSchema schemaAfterSerialize = schemaGenerator.Generate(customObjectAfterSerialize.GetType());
```

But now the `.Properties` property of the JSON schema object is `null`.

How can I get a **JSON schema** from an *arbitrary* piece of **JSON data**?

Comment: In the first call to Generate you are passing a true dynamic object but in the second one you are passing a JObject. Not sure how to fix it but that may help you find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic in your first example is a reference to an anonymous typed object.

dynamic in your second example is untyped.

It isn't possible to generate a schema from an untyped object.

Comment: An idea to resolve this request ? How to transform a json to anonymous typed object compatible with the SchemaGenerator ?